# Does Sequelize support Insert on duplicate key update?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a Model or Instance method that will perform an insert or update, depending on the whether or not the record exists? Preferably making use of MySQL's "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" syntax?

Answer (score 27):

they have recently added this feature [`upsert` or `insertOrUpdate`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#upsertvalues-options-promisecreated)

```
  /** 
  * Insert or update a single row. An update will be executed if a row
  * which matches the supplied values on either the primary key or a unique
  * key is found. Note that the unique index must be defined in your sequelize
  * model and not just in the table. Otherwise you may experience a unique 
  * constraint violation, because sequelize fails to identify the row that
  * should be updated.
  */

  Model.upsert({uniqueKey: 1234, name: 'joe'}).then(function () {
        // cheer for joy
  });
```

Answer (score 8):

Sequelize does not currently support upsert - I believe it was hard to introduce a good cross dialect solution.

You can however do a findOrCreate and a updateAttributes.

Edit: Sequelize does now support UPSERT with a pretty decent cross dialect implementation, see: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/2518

Comment: Hello!
I am facing a similar issue. I have a User model with id as primary key which is set to auto increment. This model also has a unique key which is "username". I am using the findOrCreate method to create or lookup a user based on the "username" field. My code creates a record if it does not exist but throws a UniqueConstraintError (ER_DUP_ENTRY) --> SequelizeUniqueContraintError on the "username" field when I try to find this record. Basically the findOrCreate tries to create a record for the second time instead of finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use [upsert](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-upsert) in Sequelize